# Concatenate two columns in AWS lamda function for AWS firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am new to AWS lamda and AWS firehose (trying to learn). I have a requirement to concatenate two columns in my streaming data and add it in the output stream which is stored in redshift.

Can somebody please help.

Thanks

Comment: Concatenating columns is simple inside the database.  Are there reasons for not pursuing this approach?

Comment: I am just trying a simple prototype to transform the records using lamda function ,AWS kinesis and firehose